# Separating address elements from addresses in different structures in excel 2010

Tags: excel

I've tried finding a formula but really just can't seem to find it at all!

My problem is i have thousands of addresses in different structures but i need to find the city in each of them!

So the different types of addresses i have are as follows:

Dornocktown, Dornock, Annan, DG12 6SU

Grainshore Road, Hatston, Kirkwall, KW15 1FL

Brandon Road, Watton, Thetford, IP25 6LW

Bainbridge, Leyburn, DL8 3EP

Shore Road, Dornoch, IV25 3LS

Boston Industrial Estate, Power Station Road, Rugeley, WS15 2HS

Parkfield Road, Wolverhampton, WV4 6EH

I need the city or the last word before the post code.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, values in A1:A7:

In B1 write:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-1-FIND("#";SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";"#";LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";""))-1)))
```

copy till B7

now in C1 write:

```
=LEFT(B1;FIND(",";B1)-1)
```

copy till C7

Now you have the city names. It is possible to do everything in one formula but will be a very big one...
Depending on your settings you may need to replace ";" by "," for field separators

Comment: Thank you this is perfect you're my hero!